# Как несколько напоминаний добавить в AlarmManager  и как их потом различать?

Tags: android, java

Появилась необходимость работать с AlarmManager.

В приложении создаются несколько напоминаний(Менеджер задач). Вопрос в том, как несколько напоминаний добавить в AlarmManager  и как их потом различать? И если что-то необходимо удалить, то как удалить именно одно напоминание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PendingIntent`, передающийся, как аргумент методов `set*`/`cancel` и является идентификатором задачи `AlarmManager`'а.

Например, смотрим документацию на метод [`AlarmManager.cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Remove any **alarms with a matching Intent**. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent matches this one (**as defined by filterEquals(Intent)**), will be canceled.

Ну а в [`Intent.filterEquals()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) можно найти детали, касательно алгоритма сравнения `Intent`'ов:

> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution (filtering). That is, **if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same**. This **does not compare any extra data** included in the intents.

Comment: @falstaf 
Создание PendingIntent :
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
Мы его передаем как аргумент. А при создании нескольких чем они отличаются? Тут именно не поняла как удалить тот, что нужно

Comment: > чем отличаются?

Например, содержимым `data` `Intent`'а, который используете для создания `PendingIntent`'а.

Comment: @falstaf. Буду пробовать. Спасибо :)